# Link to edited question in top bar achievements dialog points to the wrong site

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I just edited [a question](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/invalid-signed-integer-in-c-and-similar-languages) on *[Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/tour)*. The [edit was approved](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1236) and I got +2 rep and a notification about it.  But clicking the notification in the top bar brought me to [a random post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/invalid-signed-integer-in-c-and-similar-languages) on the site I happened to be reading at the time, which just happened to share the numeric post ID of the question I edited.

Checking the HTML in the top bar achievements popup; the cause is obvious: the link uses a relative URL instead of an absolute one, and thus always points to the current site:

[image: Screenshot]

Please fix this so that all cross-site links in the top bar use absolute URLs like they should.

(PS: The "similar questions" suggestion box pointed me to [this old bug report from 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209136/achievements-dropdown-links-are-pointing-to-the-wrong-site). That bug was fixed soon after it was reported, but apparently there's a new regression now.)

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.